# Get all pages under a root category ID in belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is a challenge I'm trying to solve for the last few hours.

I have a `Page` model and a `Category` model.

a page can be under many categories and each category can have multiple pages so they have a many-to-many relationship between them.

On top of that, each category has a parent category so we have a one-to-many between each category.

So, with all that in mind, here are the models:

**Page Model**

```
// table ['id', 'title', 'content', 'created_at', ...]
class Page extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Category Model**

```
// table ['id', 'category_id', 'name', 'created_at', ...]
class Category extends Model
{
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class)
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

I do have a `category_page` table with `category_id` and `page_id` to link that relationship.

Now comes the tricky part.

I'm trying to create an Eloquent query that given a `category_id` I'd be able to get all pages under this category and all the pages under this category's children categories.

I can probably achieve that with multiple joins in a nested SQL query or maybe a simple `foreach` loop to recursively get children pages (but that would cost plenty of unnecessary time).

Any ideas on a nice elegant way of doing that?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

There is a way in Laravel to do a recursive relationship and have all the sub-categories with pages in a single line of code.

// in Category model

```
public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('childrenCategories');
}
```

Now I can do

```
Category::whereId($rootCategoryId)->with('childrenCategories')->first();
```

And this way I'll have a nested tree of all categories, then I can load the pages relationship to it and I'm done.

But, there is a huge problem with it, the amount of queries it performs is crazy (a query for each nested level) and doesn't make sense to have it in a production application.
So I do have a solution, it is terrible, so I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with id, you could use nested `whereHas()`:

```
$pages = Page
    ::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
        $query
            ->where('categories.id', $categoryId)
            ->orWhereHas('parent', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
                $query->where('id', $categoryId);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

If you are working with model you have 2 options:

1) Nested `whereHas()` method:

```
$pages = Page
    ::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
        $query
            ->where('id', $category->id)
            ->orWhereHas('parent', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('id', $category->id);
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

2) Collect current category id and her children ids, then use one `whereHas()` method.

```
$categoryIds = $category->categories->pluck('id')->push($category->id);

$pages = Page
    ::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryIds) {
        $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categoryIds);
    })
    ->get();
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it looks like your queries will get me no more than one level down (category->pages and sub-categories->pages). If I want to get all the way down from the current category ID (could be 3-4 levels deep sometimes) it won't work. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your table structure is not effective for this. You should look on nested set technique (good implementation in laravel - https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset). It allows you to get all descendant categories in one query, and then you could get pages for them by second query.